# Best way to bulk create models within Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am creating a feature which involves creating voucher codes for discounts. I contain an input which the user can fill out with the specific amount they want.

When it hits the store method say if the user has entered 15 vouchers how would you create that many model records in one go?

From looking at the laravel documentation the only thing i've seen is using factories so i've attempted this below.

```
public function storeCodes(Request $request, VoucherGroup $voucherGroup)
{
    VoucherCode::create([
        'code' => $this->generateUniqueCode(),
        'group_id' => $voucherGroup->id,
        'used' => 0
    ]);

    session()->flash('success', 'successfully created codes.');

    return back();
}

 private function generateUniqueCode()
    {
        $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersNumber = strlen($characters);
        $code = '';

        while (strlen($code) < 6) {
            $position = rand(0, $charactersNumber - 1);
            $character = $characters[$position];
            $code = $code . $character;
        }

        if (VoucherCode::where('code', $code)->exists()) {
            dd('lol');
            $this->generateUniqueCode();
        }

        return $code;
    }
```

**Input**

```
<x-inputs.input size="6" type="number" name="voucher_amount" required>How many Voucher codes do you want
                to
                generate?
            </x-inputs.input>
```

The problem is it creates the models but the code returns the same code for each model.

How would I create 15 models in one call with unique code fields?

Comment: You can make an array of items and use `Model::insert()`, but you will need to make your own timestamps if applicable.

Comment: Put your create Function inside a for loop.

Comment: @Lowtiercoder can you share the method `generateUniqueCode();`

Comment: Maik Lowrey I've added the full code so the html input is the amount of records that need creating and the code needs to be unique for each one. I tried the below answer but its stuck looping creating instead of exiting based on the input

Comment: @reans but with insert can you specify how many records to create if i pass a number from the input, from looking at examples you need to manually add this yourself?

Comment: @Lowtiercoder And where you define how many vouchers are createing? You got by the request have voucher_amount.

Comment: @MaikLowrey the answer below actually solved it until the creator deleted it - was a typo on my end, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop below solved this for me. It was originally posted by someone but its been deleted recently so ill answer the question below but thanks to whoever provided it!

```
$newVouchers = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $request->voucher_amount; $i++) {
            $newVouchers[] = VoucherCode::create([
                'code' => $this->generateUniqueCode(),
                'group_id' => $voucherGroup->id,
                'used' => 0
            ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it shortly

```
do {
    //generate unique code
    $uniqueCode = strtoupper(substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 15));
} while (VoucherCode::where('code', $uniqueCode)->exists());

VoucherCode::create([
    'code' => $uniqueCode,
    'group_id' => $voucherGroup->id,
    'used' => 0
]);

session()->flash('success', 'successfully created codes.');

return back();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Insert Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#insert-statements) to bulk create models

$vouchers = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfVoucher; $i++) {
$vouchers[] = [
'code' => $this->generateUniqueCode(),
'group_id' => $voucherGroup->id,
'used' => 0
];
}
DB::table('users')->insert($vouchers);